# clustering wso2 api manager gateway

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

i'm trying to cluster wso2 api manager 1.10 gateway into 3 host using tutorial here : https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+the+Gateway, but some of the steps are confusing.
As i know, wso2 api manager has two transport which is

1.) servlet transport (tomcat) located at port 9443 (https) and 9763 (http) used to serve carbon related service

2.) PTT/NIO transport (axis2) located at port 8243 (https) and 8280 (http) used to serve requests to deployment artifacts.

What i don't understand from the tutorial is :

1.) why should there be a port mapping in the clustering configuration (located in axis2 configuration) of the gateway manager component?

```
<parameter name="properties">
    <property name="backendServerURL" value="https://${hostName}:${httpsPort}/services/"/>
    <property name="mgtConsoleURL" value="https://${hostName}:${httpsPort}/"/>
    <property name="subDomain" value="mgt"/>
    <property name="port.mapping.80" value="9763"/>
    <property name="port.mapping.443" value="9443"/>
</parameter>
```

isn't it already defined in load balancer (nginx) configuration

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name mgt.am.wso2.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mgt.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mgt.key;

    location / {
               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
               proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
               proxy_read_timeout 5m;
               proxy_send_timeout 5m;
               proxy_pass https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx3:9443/;
        }
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/mgt-error.log ;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/mgt-access.log;
}
```

and in tomcat configuration?

```
<Connector  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" port="9763" proxyPort="80" ... />
<Connector  protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" port="9443" proxyPort="443"/>
```

2.) Why does the load balancer configuration for gateway worker use the servlet port? shouldn't it be the PTT/NIO port? (since the gateway worker are used to serve requests to deployment artifacts)

```
upstream wso2.am.com {
        sticky cookie JSESSIONID;
        server xxx.xxx.xxx.xx4:9763;
        server xxx.xxx.xxx.xx5:9763;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name am.wso2.com;
        location / {
               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
               proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
               proxy_read_timeout 5m;
               proxy_send_timeout 5m;
               proxy_pass http://wso2.am.com;
        }
}

upstream ssl.wso2.am.com {
    sticky cookie JSESSIONID;
    server xxx.xxx.xxx.xx4:9443;
    server xxx.xxx.xxx.xx5:9443;
}

server {
listen 443;
    server_name am.wso2.com;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/wrk.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/wrk.key;
    location / {
               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
               proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
               proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
               proxy_read_timeout 5m;
               proxy_send_timeout 5m;
               proxy_pass https://ssl.wso2.am.com;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There are two of transport ports in API Manager, PTT and servlet. When a request comes into the API Manager, it always goes to the default transport which is the PTT/NIO transport.
   When the admin services are called (ex: Publishing API),  you send a servlet request. If you do not specify the port mapping parameter in the manager node, it would hit the PTT/NIO transport and the request would fail.
2. Here, it has specified a common example for load balancer config. Your config needs to be changed according to Gateway worker.

Comment: hi, thanks for your response, but i'm still confused
1.) as i know PTT/NIO transport are on ports 8280 & 8243, while the management console ports are in 9443 & 9763, If we set up a proxy pass in nginx like this, 'proxy_pass https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx3:9443/', how can the request be passed to PTT/NIO port?

Comment: it is set on axis2.xml not in the nginx.